# ros2 launch xml example

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see that a yaml and xml front-end was added to ros2. In the [feature request](https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/163) I see that there was intent to add support for these to the `ros2launch` cli, but I am struggling to create a `.launch.xml` file and launch it with `ros2launch`

Are there any full examples of creating an xml launch file and then using the launch cli tool to run it? The design document and the test [here](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/f906510021b4ed98e8247dc785372e2fe383bf85/test_launch_ros/test/test_launch_ros/frontend/test_node_frontend.py) show me the syntax, but I'm still unsuccessful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341128/ros2-launch-xml-example/) by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 553 on 2020-01-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a tutorial about how to migrate launchfiles from ROS1 to ROS2: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Launch-files-migration-guide/.

There are some XML examples in the demos, e.g. in this folder: https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/demo_nodes_cpp/launch/topics.

It would be a great contribution to add more examples to the demos.

About your questions in the github issue:

> If I have a launch file, how can I get it running?

```
ros2 launch /path/to/file_launch.xml
```

> Do I need to create a package, do I need to add it in package.xml whatsoever...

No necessarily, as commented above.
If you do want to install some launchfiles with a package, you can:

- (cpp package): https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/948b4f4869298f39cfe99d3ae517ad60a72a8909/demo_nodes_cpp/CMakeLists.txt#L207-L211
- (python package): Install the launchfiles in the share folder using `data_files` argument of setuptools `setup`. Like [here](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/ae12701630c7acd3d78806bc764bf96b54d6ebe8/launch/setup.py#L11), but with a launchfile.

In those cases, you will be able to do:

```
ros2 launch package_name name_of_launch_file_launch.xml
```

In case you have problems running a specific launchfile, you can copy it here and I will try to help.

Best,

Ivan

---

Originally posted by [ivanpauno](https://answers.ros.org/users/44086/ivanpauno/) with karma: 86 on 2020-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [urczf](https://answers.ros.org/users/33354/urczf/) on 2020-03-24**:
That worked, thanks! Nonetheless, I would add it somewhere on index.ros.org